# Как должна быть реализована композиция?

Tags: ооп, классы, шаблоны-проектирования, инспекция-кода

Почти во всех книгах и статьях говорят о склонностях в пользу композиции, а не наследования. Но у меня при её реализации немного хромает разум.  
Для примера реализации приведу псевдокод:

```
class A {
    function a( ){}
    function b( ){}
    function c( ){}
}

class B {
    function a( ){
        a.a( );
    }
    function b( ){
        a.b( );
    }
    function c( ){
        a.c( );
    }
    function d( ){}
    function e( ){}
}

class C {
    function a( ){
        b.a( );
    }
    function b( ){
        b.b( );
    }
    function c( ){
        b.c( );
    }
    function d( ){
        b.d( );
    }
    function e( ){
        b.e( );
    }
}
```

Разве это не является избыточным? Или при наследовании классов все то же самое?

Comment: Вообще, на мой взгляд, приведенный вами пример будет актуален только в том, случае если вы используете паттерн Adapter.

Comment: Нет, адаптер я не использую, я на деле показываю то, что называют лучшим вариантом те, кто пишет книги. Но у меня такой вариант вызывает сомнения, и поэтому я решил спросить - почему ЭТО лучше чем наследование?

Comment: Кхм...
Лучший вариант зависит от ситуации :)

Если не вдаваться в подробности, то лучший вариант в данном случае является "Наследование".

Вполне возможно, автор книги говорил перед примером что-то умное, о чем вы умолчали.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Должно быть одинаково и при наследовании.

```
class A {
public:
    function a( ){}
    function b( ){}
    function c( ){}
};

class B: public A{
public:
    function d( ){}
    function e( ){}
};

class C: public B{};
```

Comment: Я не понял... Вы говорите о том, что мой вариант с композицией идентичен наследованию? То есть при наследовании за кулисами остается все та же куча методов?

Comment: WAT?

Можно и так, сказать. Результат будет один и тот же.

Comment: Т.е. Класс B будет содержать все методы класса A, при этом вы не пилите кучу лишнего кода.